# How i can find DIR which is present in last in list

Tags: python

```
import ftplib  
import re
import string
ftp = ftplib.FTP('')    # For access FTP link.
ftp.login ("")
ftpdir = ftp.cwd('')
data=[]
ftp.dir(data.append)
for line in data:
    string.find("DIR","data")
    if "DIR" in line:
           print line
```

With this code i got list of DIR names present in FTP server, now how i can find DIR which is present in last in list.

My output is:

```
12-09-11  10:04PM       <DIR>          mcl_201147_hw79u_05
    12-08-11  01:19AM       <DIR>          mcl_201148_hw79u_02
    12-16-11  12:53PM       <DIR>          mcl_201149_hw79u_07
    12-25-11  12:11AM       <DIR>          mcl_201150_hw79u_05
    01-07-12  12:00AM       <DIR>          mcl_201151_hw79u_04
    01-07-12  11:37PM       <DIR>          mcl_201152_hw79u_05
    01-17-12  01:06AM       <DIR>          mcl_201201_hw79u_04
    01-29-12  12:52AM       <DIR>          mcl_201202_hw79u_04
    02-04-12  01:06AM       <DIR>          mcl_201203_hw79u_03
    02-11-12  01:28AM       <DIR>          mcl_201204_hw79u_05
    02-17-12  01:12AM       <DIR>          mcl_201205_hw79u_05
    02-19-12  01:22AM       <DIR>          mcl_201206_hw79u_05
    03-02-12  02:24AM       <DIR>          mcl_201207_hw79u_05
    03-04-12  02:01AM       <DIR>          mcl_201208_hw79u_05
    03-05-12  12:25PM       <DIR>          mcl_201209_hw79u_06
```

i want to find last DIR present in list (03-05-12  12:25PM                 mcl_201209_hw79u_06)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a list, you do this

```
try:
  return data[-1]
except IndexError as e:
  return e
// in your code you can just print "e" and you can continue like this...

// version two demonstrate why try, except is useful

def getdir(data):
   try:
     data[-1]
   except IndexError as e:
     return e

....
print getdir(data)    
print 1+1
```

Suppose something is wrong with indexing the list, program will not halt:

```
list index out of range
2
```

Is this what you want?

---

To be useful, you should use logger to keep track of `e` (error message), and instead, returns a default value (like `None`) so you know there is something wrong / no directory exists.

And I am not sure what's the use of `string` module here. I rarely use that module if it's just finding something I need in a list.

---

Please give me these descriptions and edit your original post.

1. give me the results of `print line`
2. give me the result of `print data`
3. what is this `dir` you want?

While answering my questions, you probably can figure out how to solve it.

Thanks.

---

Okay. So I assume that each line is a record of the form:

`12-09-11  10:04PM       <DIR>          mcl_201147_hw79u_05`
Assuming you don't have a way to keep the `time`, `<DIR>`, and `dir-name` separate, you would do this

```
mystring = "12-09-11  10:04PM       <DIR>          mcl_201147_hw79u_05"
dirname = mystring.split(" ")[-1]
// ['12-09-11', '', '10:04PM', '', '', '', '', '', '', '<DIR>', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'mcl_201147_hw79u_05']
// and [-1] indicates the last element in the list (in reverse order)
```

You can also try to `' '.join(mystring.split())` first, then apply `split()` (without any argument), but I think doing the `split` right away is easier and more memory efficient as the first method would only create one list, and the alternative method will create two lists.

If `lines` are not already `str` type, try to see if `str(line)` helps.

If you ever need to find all the `dirname`, please google `list comprehension`. It's considered to be more efficient than loops. It's a compact way of writing what you were going to achieve... with, of course, proper stripping per your requirement.

Comment: thanks .. i have a different kinds of files in FTP location, i want only DIR, when i get all DIR names i want to find DIR present in last location.

Comment: @user1227493 I am sorry, but I don't quite understand the requirement. So what is in `data`? Directories and files? What do you mean `find directory presents in the last location`? See my edit so I can help.

Comment: my output is01-29-12  12:52AM       <DIR>          mcl_201202_hw79u_04
    02-04-12  01:06AM       <DIR>          mcl_201203_hw79u_03
    02-11-12  01:28AM       <DIR>          mcl_201204_hw79u_05
    02-17-12  01:12AM       <DIR>          mcl_201205_hw79u_05
    02-19-12  01:22AM       <DIR>          mcl_201206_hw79u_05
    03-02-12  02:24AM       <DIR>          mcl_201207_hw79u_05
    03-04-12  02:01AM       <DIR>          mcl_201208_hw79u_05
    03-05-12  12:25PM       <DIR>          mcl_201209_hw79u_06

i want to find last DIR present in list (03-05-12 12:25PM mcl_201209_hw79u_06)

Answer (score 0):

```
import ftplib  # For access FTP module
ftp = ftplib.FTP('')  # For access FTP link
ftp.login ('')
ftpdir = ftp.cwd('Working Directory')
list = []
ftp.dir(list.append)  # append all the ftp files in list 
temp = []  # Temp list 
for item in list:
    if item.find('DIR') != -1:
        temp.append(item)
a = 0              
for item in temp:
    a = a + 1 
print temp[-1]
```

Finally I am able to solve my problem with the help of the above code we are able to filter list of all directory and after that we are able to find directory which is located in last. Thanks to all for help.